# jQuery: Sticky navigation bar changes margins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a navigation bar that moves when page scrolls, this is jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {  
    var stickyNavTop = $('.nav').offset().top;  
    var stickyNav = function(){  
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  
    if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {   
        $('.nav').addClass('sticky');
    } else {  
        $('.nav').removeClass('sticky');   
      }  
    };  

    stickyNav();  

    $(window).scroll(function() {  
        stickyNav();  
    });  
    });
```

And CSS

```
.sticky {  
        position: fixed;  
        width: 100%;  
        left: 0;  
        top: 0;  
        border-top: 0;  
    }
```

The problem is that when the navigation bar position gets fixed, the main content under the navigation bar rearrange the margin because it thinks that the navigation bar has been removed but I don't want this, I want my boxes stay in their places.
What should I do?

Here is jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/omidh/cvjt0eLL/6/

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This workaround keeps your markup as it is, with minimal edits to the jQuery and CSS, see the demo and code below.

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/cvjt0eLL/10/

Added CSS:

```
.push {
    margin-top: 50px; /*same height as navbar*/
}
```

Updated jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var stickyNavTop = $('.nav').offset().top;
     var stickyNav = function () {
         var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
         if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {
             $('.nav').addClass('sticky');
             $('.content').addClass('push'); // added
         } else {
             $('.nav').removeClass('sticky');
             $('.content').removeClass('push'); //added
         }
     };

     stickyNav();

     $(window).scroll(function () {
         stickyNav();
     });
 });
```